# Magento EcomDev PHPUnit Customer fixtures are not being loaded

Tags: magento, phpunit

I have a case where i want to check if a customer already exists in the database. I have created a fixture file for this:

```
scope:
  website:
    - website_id: 1
      code: main
      name: Main Website
      default_group_id: 1
  group:
    - group_id: 1
      website_id: 1
      name: Main Website Store
      root_category_id: 8
      default_store_id: 1
  store:
    - store_id: 1
      code: default
      website_id: 1
      group_id: 1
      name: Default Store View
      is_active: 1
eav:
  customer:
    - entity_id: 13
      entity_type_id: 1
      website_id: 1
      email: example@example.com
      group_id: 1
      store_id: 1
      is_active: 1
      firstname: john
      lastname: smith
```

When i run the test, i get the error:

```
Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'sort_order' in order clause is ambiguous
```

This error only occurs when i load the fixture, so i think it has something to do with the Model_Fixture_Eav class. I am not sure which methods i should implement to create an EAV Model for customers. Has anyone managed to successfully import customer fixtures before?

Answer (score 3):

```
eav:
    customer:
        - entity_id: 13
          entity_type_id: 1
          attribute_set_id: 0
          website_id: 1
          email: example@example.com
          group_id: 1
          store_id: 1
          is_active: 1
          firstname: john
          lastname: smith
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question? This would be very helpful to the person asking the question, and anyone else who comes along.